# passing data from one frame and setting it in textfield in another frame retrieving corresponding data from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I am working on a NetBeans project (Java Swings) using MySQL @ the back ground. Got struck in this particular scenario.

I am working with a `JTable` in one frame, say `frame1` from where a row has to be selected on 'onclick' action event.

The corresponding data from the table in background in mysql  will be retrieved and the data  to be passed on to another frame, say `frame2` where the data will be set to a `JTextField`.

The table in `frame1` contains only a few selected tuples of the whole table maintained in the database.

The following are the code snippets i used
::
database table name DB_table

1- Select the data from the table in frame1

```
public static String Table;
public static int row;
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)                    
{                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton3.setEnabled(true);
    row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    Table = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
}
```

2- The action event on the button to redirect it to frame2

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    frame2 ac =new frame2();
    jDesktopPane1.add(ac);
    try {
        ac.setSelectedRow(Table);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Logger.getLogger(showp1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    ac.setVisible(true);
}
```

3- this is the method in frame2

```
void setSelectedRow(String Table) {
    try {
        //ResultSet resultSet = null;
        System.out.print(Table);

        rs = pst.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DB_Table where attr="+ Table +"");
        //System.out.print(Table);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(Table);
            //jTextField1.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
            //System.out.print(Table);
            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("attr"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The data is being printed in the output console but not being stored in the text field in `frame2`...

Hope I am clear with the problem

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated..

Comment: 2- The action event on the button to redirect it to frame2. How did u redirect , setSelectedRow is setting the method to frame1 only

Comment: @bunta i have stored the value in the variable 'Table', from the table in frame1 and passed it to frame2,where the method setSelectedRow in the frame2 is to access it....

Comment: ac.setSelectedRow(Table); is this the method which sets to frame2?

Comment: yes,this method sends the variable 'table' to frame2

Comment: as I see , ac is an instance of frame1 , not frame2.

Comment: okk.... thats a typo..supposed to be frame2 ac =new frame2();...!! hope its clear now

Comment: More clear would be to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.